# How to shift ubuntu OS from Logical Partition to Primary Partition?

Tags: partitioning, iso, disk-image

I was new to Linux and Partition concepts when I installed Ubuntu on my machine, which already ran windows 7. At first, I created some unallocated space (~100GB). But at that time, I didn't know it was in Extended partitions section.And because of that, Ubuntu was installed in Extended Partition section.

Now I have to increase the size of my ubuntu logical partition. But not enough space is left in th eextended partition section. So, I'm thinking of moving the OS from Extended Partition section to Primary partition, which already contains windows 7 (My machine has both OS).
So, my question is, which is the most optimal way to remove ubuntu from logical partition, and also retain windows in primary partition?
Thanks for answering.

Some extra info before finishing. My extended partition constains 2 logial partitions, one of which contains ubuntu. The other partition is unallocated space. I tried a lot to merge them, to get a larger space for ubuntu. I don't know why, but I'm unable to merge those two partitions.
If possible, plz do provide a sol. to this as well.

Thanks again.

Comment: You cannot increase the size of a partition that is in-use (or mounted). If you were using the partition and tried to use the unallocated space that is also within the extended partition, the failure was because it was mounted. The easiest way around this issue is use 'live' media (eg. Ubuntu install media), then expand your partition in size. Note: if using `grub` as a bootloader, and the location of /boot/grub is moved; it may require the re-installation of the MBR, but I'd do that only if it fails to boot (ie. boot 'live' media again then fix..)   *this is likely less detail that needed*

Comment: Actually, while dealing with the unallocated space in extended partitions, I messed up with it, somehow, and later, while restarting the system, my computer couldn't boot properly. I had to type in some DOS commmands (I think) in the command-line which appears before any OS boots, and later update grub to correct the error. From then on, I'm not trying anything new with stuff like that lol :)

Comment: So, you are saying, I could only merge these logical partitons only when they are not being used. Then, is it possible to merge them, using windows, which is in a primary partition?

Comment: Un-allocated space is space that haven't yet been allocated to any partition, so you only need to grow the one partition to utilize the unallocated spce. Merging partitions is a different thing.  You haven't said what type of *file system* your partition is in, but windows cannot by default (the addition of extra software) read and make changes to common Ubuntu partitions (eg. ext4, xfs, btrfs, etc). Even if you do have additional software loaded in windows, as it's not a native *fs* in windows, I'd not do it it in windows (regardless ensure you have good backups of **all** files systems)